# Flask - UndefinedError: 'restaurant_id' is undefined

Tags: python, flask, url-routing, function

I try to reference another page from this page

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
          <header>
              <h1>Restaurants<h1>
          </header>


          {% for i in restaurants %}

          <h5>
              <a href= "*">
                  {{i.name}}
              </a>
            &nbsp &nbsp
              <a href = "*">  Edit </a> &nbsp
              <a href = "*">  Delete  </a>
          </h5>

           {% endfor %}

        <a href = {{url_for('newRestaurant', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)}}> Create new restaurant </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my web server from where I manage the routes:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database_setup import Base, Restaurant, MenuItem

app = Flask(__name__)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
session = DBSession()

# Show all restaurants 
.....

#Create new restaurants
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>/new', methods = ['GET','POS'])
def newRestaurant(restaurant_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_Restaurant = Restaurant(name = request.form['new_restaurant_name'], restaurant_id = restaurant_id)
        session.add(new_Restaurant)
        session.commit()
    #return "This page will be for making a new restaurant"
        flash("new restaurant create")
        return redirect(url_for('restaurants', restaurant_id = restaurant_id))
    else:
        return render('newRestaurant.html', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)
```

Here I am trying to route to my create restaurant page  :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Comment: Please try to get your formatting right (check the preview area while you type). You won't get answers if your post is hard to read. I'll fix that for you for now.

Comment: Can you provide the steps to recreate the error. From what I understand the view to the Jinja2 template does not know what the restaurant_id is

Comment: For that i need to paste the whole webserver.py, how do u want me to send it to you, or do ypu have a way for me to share it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't send anything to `restaurant_id` in the jinja template:

```
{{url_for('newRestaurant', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)}}
```

the second `restaurant_id` is not defined because you're not sending any value through it to the template.

You should send a number from your `newRestaurant` function.

For example (and this is only a simple example), you could verify if there is no row in the Restaurant table and if it isn't you initiate `restaurant_id = 1`:

**EDITED**

```
@app.route('/restaurant/<int:restaurant_id>', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def newRestaurant(restaurant_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        .............
    else:
        restaurants = session.query(Restaurant).all()
        if not restaurants:
            restaurant_id = 1
        else:
            nr_restaurants = session.query(Restaurant).count()
            restaurant_id = int(nr_restaurants) + 1
        return render_template('newRestaurant.html', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)
```

now you are sending a number to the template through `restaurant_id` variable and you can use it there.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion carefully and understood it. Thank you so much. Never the less after executing it, i still get the same error ( UndefinedError: 'restaurant_id' is undefined)

Comment: Edited: you've written `POS` instead of `POST` and I removed `/new` from the route. Try it. You also should put the code of the template page with the form which sends the `POST`.

Comment: The function which renders the template is `render_template` and not `render`.

Comment: Sorry but i dont get your what you mean by "put the code of the template page with the form which sends the POST".

Comment: A `POST` request is usually sent from a form through its `method` attribute.  You should read about [HTTP methods](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods.htm).

Comment: actually yes, i edited the post , and followed your example above for the restaurant id to return a number . The same error UndefinedError: 'restaurant_id' is undefined in the template. The link is just expected to take me to the new restaurant page .   <a href = '{{url_for('newRestaurant', restaurant_id = restaurant_id)}}'> Create new restaurant </a>

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue and here is how

Given that all i needed was to create a new restaurant, i didnt need to capture the id of the restaurant on the url. so instead to routing like this

@app.route('/restaurant//new', methods = ['GET','POST'])

i removed the id part and removed the argument in the def newRestaurant function like this

@app.route('/restaurant/new', methods = ['GET','POST'])

Many thanks to you all , for the clues

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I added `restaurant_id=restaurant_id` under my `deleteMenuItem` definition.

[image]